# Cyclic dependency found

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Cyclic dependency found. coupons is
>   dependent of itself. Dependency chain: coupons -> orders => coupons

My `order.js` model looks like as follows:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => 
{
    var Order = sequelize.define('orders', 
    {
        id: 
        {
              allowNull: false,
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true,
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },

        userid: 
        {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,

            references: 
            {
                model: 'users',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },

        coupon_id:
        {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,

            references: 
            {
                model: 'coupons',
                key: 'id'
            },

        },

        product: 
        {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,

            references: 
            {
                model: 'products',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },

        address: 
        {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,

            references: 
            {
                model: 'address',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },

        canceled:
        {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0
        },

        quantity: 
        {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },

        note: 
        {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },

    },

    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'orders',
        createdAt: 'createdat',
        updatedAt: 'updatedat',

    });

    Order.associate = models => {
        Order.hasMany(models.coupons, {
          foreignKey: 'id',
          onDelete: 'cascade',
          onUpdate: 'cascade',
          constrains: false
        });
      };


    return Order;
};
```

and `coupon.js` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => 
{
    var Coupon = sequelize.define('coupons', 
    {
        id: 
        {
              allowNull: false,
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true,
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },

        name: 
        {
             type: DataTypes.STRING
        },

        code: 
        {
             type: DataTypes.STRING
        },

        discount:
        {
             type: DataTypes.FLOAT
        },

        expires: 
        {
              type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        },

        created_by: 
        {
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER,

              references: 
              {
                    model: 'users',
                    key: 'id'
              },

        },

        maxuse: 
        {
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },

    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'coupons',
        createdAt: 'createdat',
        updatedAt: 'updatedat'

    });


    Coupon.associate = models => {
      Coupon.belongsTo(models.orders, 
      {
        foreignKey: 'id',
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
      });
    };


    return Coupon;
};
```

It seems that I am doing something wrong with the associations. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: Everytime I comment out `coupon_id:` on orders.js, the error goes out. Still, I need this functionality.

Comment: Could the issue be with the `foreignKey` attribute - this refers to the field in the current table which saves the id for the other model - so if you wanted the coupon to save the link to an order via an `orderId` field you would declare the `foreignKey` on the `Coupon.belongsTo` as being `orderId` instead of `id`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did modify both foreignKey to orderId and I still the same.

Comment: Try `constraints: false` - see https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#cyclic-dependencies--amp--disabling-constraints

Comment: OK, so this worked: "constraints: false". Also, I did swap belongsTo to the Order model and hasMany to the Coupon one. I am not 100% certain why the swap fixed the issue, but would be more than happy to receive feedbacks. Thanks @madebydavid.